# Pact JS: how to publish to a pact-broker

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pact

I'm trying to publish my pact-file to a pact broker I have set up.  According to the [docs](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/#publishing-pacts-to-a-broker), this is done by importing `@pact-foundation/pact-node` and calling `publishPacts()`.

However, that function doesn't exist. I've installed the module using `npm install @pact-foundation/pact-node --save`, as the docs say, then `require`d it, but when I attempt to publish, I get `TypeError: pact.publishPacts is not a function`.  When I `require` from the interactive node shell, I get this:

```
> const pact = require('@pact-foundation/pact-node')
undefined
> pact
{ default: Pact { __servers: [] } }
>
```

What's going on here? If I navigate into `node_modules/pact/node_modules` and import the module form there, I get the `publishPacts` method just fine. But my actual test cases can't find the version of `@pact-foundation/pact-node` that was installed with `pact`. Only the version that I installed separately, which seems to be broken.

Comment: This looks like a bug, could you please raise on the pact-node repository?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with `v5.1.0`:

```
import pact from '@pact-foundation/pact-node';
import * as path from 'path';

const opts = {
  pactUrls: [path.resolve(__dirname, './pacts/matching_service-animal_profile_service.json')],
  pactBroker: 'https://test.pact.dius.com.au',
  pactBrokerUsername: 'blah',
  pactBrokerPassword: 'blah',
  tags: ['prod', 'test'],
  consumerVersion: '1.0.0'
}
pact.publishPacts(opts)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Pact contract publishing complete!')
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log('Pact contract publishing failed: ', e)
  })
```

Comment: it looks like this actually was a bug in 5.1.0.  they [fixed](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-node/releases/tag/5.1.1) it last night.

Comment: @Matthew Fellows is there a way to make consumerVersion and tag dynamic so we can pass it in via Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: You would save username and password as environment variables and access them: 
pactBrokerUsername: process.env.PACT_USERNAME,
pactBrokerPassword: process.env.PACT_PASSWORD

Comment: Of course, it's just JavaScript code. What are you having trouble with? I think it's a separate question